# Задача "ЛИСА + ВОЛК = ЗВЕРИ" (нужен алгоритм для написания программы)

Tags: алгоритм, логика

Подскажите, по какому алгоритму реализуется данная задача:

дана фраза: ЛИСА + ВОЛК = ЗВЕРИ
заменить каждую букву в фразе так, что бы получилось верное числовое выражение

есть ли какие то стандартные методы реализации такой задачи? в частности интересует алгоритм присвоения числового значения буквам

ЗЫ: нашла только списки подобных задач...

Comment: минут 5 заняло понять, что тут написано (при условии, что я встречал эту задачу раньше)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не для того мы тут сидим, чтоб за школьников задачи решать

Comment: мы сидим тут для того, чтобы решать задачи не за школьников, а за профессионалов! если серьеъно - это обычная переборная задача. поиск в глубину/ширину/рекурсия. попробуйте сами набросать решение. если что-то не получится - запостите сюда код, вам помогут.

Comment: эту задачу дал преподаватель Java EE, если бы это была задача из Core - я бы сюда даже не заглядывала и искала бы решение в коре. Раз уж это попало ко мне из курса ЕЕ - значит так возможет вариант решения для ЕЕ(может использует какую то из библиотек ЕЕ, я не знаю как оно там), следовательно, я спросила у людей, которые это могут знать.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант рекурсивный перебор пары буква - число. Работать будет порядка 10!*длину что на современном компьютере работает за пару секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Простейший вариант - полный перебор. Разных цифр всё равно 10, причём, после выбора 9 последняя получается однозначно. Итого менее 10^9 комбинаций. Хотя при 10 явно можно использовать `next_permutation` и получить `10!`.

Answer (score 0):

Л, В и З <> 0

И, С, А, О, К, Е, Р - любые цифры

самый простой и долгий алгоритм, это

1. создать 10 циклов,
2. потом проверить каждую переменную, что бы они не были равни друг другу
3. Вычаслить ЛИСА = Л *1000 + И * 100 + С * 10+А и ВОЛК, ЗВЕРИ
4. Проверить совподает ли условия лиса+волк=звери

вот и все

Второй метод

1. создать цикл от 1110000000 до 9999999999
2. разбыт число по цифрам
3. проверить условие

тут только операций очень много будет